# What are the operators ==> and =?>?

Tags: f#, operators

I was reading F# code when I found two operators I was not aware of.

```
"Clean"
    ==> "ResolveDependencies"
    ==> "SetBuildNumber" 
    =?> ("PatchAssemblyInfo", buildServer = TeamCity)
```

I looked into the [F# documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/) for the operators without success. I did not find anything about them. What are they?

Comment: F# tooling will usually let you hover over these and find out more about them, such as which library they came from. You should also be able to go to their definition if they are defined as custom operators inside your codebase.

Comment: The code was opened with a notepad-level editor. This is a really good advice. I just open the project with VS and the answer was there too.

Comment: Spread the word! Operator questions are common here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# supports custom operators and that's what they are. You did not look into the right documentation. I guess you are using Fake. Fake defines exactly those operators:

## AdditionalSyntax

Provides functions and operators to deal with FAKE targets and target dependencies.

### Functions and values

- `( ? ) f s`   Allows to use Tokens instead of strings
- `( ?<- ) f str action`    Allows to use Tokens instead of strings for TargetNames
- `( ?=> ) x y`     Defines a soft dependency. x must run before y, if it is present, but y does not require x to be run.
- `( <=? ) y x`     Defines a soft dependency. x must run before y, if it is present, but y does not require x to be run.
- `( <=> ) x y`     Defines that x and y are not dependent on each other but y is dependent on all dependencies of x.
- `( =?> ) x (y, condition)`    Defines a conditional dependency - y is dependent on x if the condition is true
- `( ==> ) x y`    Defines a dependency - y is dependent on x
- ...

[source](https://fake.build/apidocs/v4/fake-additionalsyntax.html)